# What kind of fonts can I use for academic presentation?

Tags: presentation, formatting

Many videos and documents say that we should use Arial as the font for academic presentation. However, I think Arial is really ugly.

Certainly, there are other fonts suitable for academic presentations. How can I recognise them? Is it just every sans-serif font or what do I need to consider?

Comment: This is probably to some extent a matter of taste. But for all things concerning academic design and layout, Edward Tufte is a classical go-to reference.

Comment: If your presentation is not about fonts, any boring font is suitable.

Comment: Not Comic Sans.

Comment: One advantage of a hideously ugly font is that you will know if someone swipes your slides and posts them online! ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I take it as given that you won’t use typefaces that are not suitable for an academic setting at all, like a comic or blackletter typeface, i.e., any typeface you that is not suitable for a printed poster either.
With those constraints, the main thing to consider is that your typeface must render well on a projector or via screencast.
Interestingly, those different settings lead to similar conclusions:

- You have to expect that projectors have low resolutions (and no [sub-pixel hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering)), which causes intricate details such as most serifs look ugly.
- For screencasts, you have to expect that they will be scaled on the viewer’s side, which again causes problems with detailed components such as most serifs and works bests with straight lines and similar.

For this reason, most sans-serif typefaces are well suited for presentations while serif typefaces are not. However you can find exceptions such as organic grotesques, which are sans serif but scale badly and render badly on low resolutions – or slab serifs, which work well with scaling as well as on low resolutions.

[image: Examples]

Comment: Does anyone know the name of the four example fonts in this answer? (Especially the two "good" examples)

Comment: @6005: The fonts from top to bottom are: Aakar, Ubuntu, Linux Biolinum and Zilla Slab. However, please note that I chose them for highlighting the aspects relevant to this answer, and not to endorse (or attack) these particular fonts.

Comment: Thank you! Understood yes